# Crontab script execution

Tags: linux, shell-script, cron

I'm trying to do a comms loss auto restart and just found this script online (bless the person who did it). the script is

```
ping -c4 www.site.com > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ] 
then
  sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
fi
```

so this script works perfectly fine. what i wanted to do was add another script with the same function but instead of pinging a site, i wanted to add another so it can ping a server, so what i did was same script but just change what it was pinging

```
ping -c4 192.168.1.5 > /dev/null

if [ $? != 0 ] 
then
  sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
fi
```

i am storing this script on `/usr/local/bin/` so the filename on the first script for the comms loss is `/usr/local/bin/commsloss.sh` and then the filename of the second script is `/usr/local/bin/serverloss.sh`

i've added both of these lines on `crontab -e`

`*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/sudo -H /usr/local/bin/commsloss.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1`

`*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/sudo -H /usr/local/bin/serverloss.sh >> /dev/null 2>&1`

and then i tried turning off the server to see if it will restart but it didn't work.

any suggestions?

i was wondering if this would work or if this is the correct syntax to use so that i can just have one script instead of two?

```
ping -c4 www.site.com > /dev/null || ping -c4 192.168.1.5 > /dev/null
```

Comment: Did you make the script execcutable?

Comment: You might check your system logs for failure messages from the cron jobs.  It is inadvisable to use `sudo` in a cron command line.  If you need a cronjob to run with root permissions, add it to a system cron table (e.g., `/etc/crontab`) as root, or add it to root's personal crontab (`sudo crontab -e`).

Comment: yes i did @val0x00ff

Comment: i read that if the script needs permission it should be under sudo crontab -e, so removed the script on crontab -e and instead did it on sudo crontab -e and it looks like it worked

Comment: Is `/usr/local/bin/serverloss.sh` executable? `check permision by `ls -la /usr/local/bin/serverloss.sh`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your current server script isn't working but this should allow you to use the `or` operator:

```
#!/bin/bash
ping -q -c4 www.site.com > /dev/null
siteup=$?
ping -q -c4 192.168.1.5 > /dev/null
ipup=$?
if [[ $siteup != "0" || $ipup != "0" ]]; then
  sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now
else
  :
fi
```